# Want to hide a tab (data-tab) using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class="total"> 
    <li data-tab="general"><i class="final"></i></li> 
    <li data-tab="normal"><i class="small"></i></li>  
</ul>
```

I have done this to hide only general tab. But it will hide the complete data. What is the best solution to do this ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tabs = $("li[data-tab='general']");
    tabs.hide();
```

Comment: I don't see how this is a Joomla related issue.

Comment: use as `$("li[data-tab='general']").hide()` Rest your code is good

Comment: I tried this but it's not working. Not hide that data-tab :(

Comment: i tried your code in jsfiddle and it's working. http://jsfiddle.net/q7f8b7dc/ . which browser are you trying it on?

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what you really want to get. But if you wanna get any element with `data-tab` attribute specified use this selector:

```
$("li[data-tab]");
```

Comment: Hello, In my post I want to hide only this tab "  
<li data-tab="general"><i class="final"></i></li> "
But when I applied above solution then it hide complete data , general , normal , ul class etc ...
So is there any way that I can only hide particular thing

Comment: If so, the problem is somewhere in the rest of your code. Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o78427cy/1/ it does exactly what you need with exactly the same code.

Comment: Yes that true.. let me figure it out and I will update you :) 
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Check `li` has `data-tab`=`general` and then hide

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var tabs = $("ul#total li");
    $.each(tabs, function () {
        if ($(this).attr('data-tab') == 'general') {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });

});
```